# Teradata - Pandas TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

I am trying to run the following code to create a Teradata table using the teradata python library:

```
import teradata
import pandas as pd

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="Hello", version="1.0",
    logConsole=False)
session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="tdprod",
    username="xxx", password="xxx");

sqlStr = "CREATE SET TABLE \"TEST123\" \
(col1 INTEGER) PRIMARY INDEX (col1);"

result = pd.read_sql(sqlStr, self.session)
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
File "..\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1436, in read_query
columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Is that the full traceback or were there lines before? If there were more lines, please include them.

Comment: I get `OSError: libodbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.  There's some dependence missing from your example.  Something else to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL (sqlStr) is a DDL (CREATE Table) -> it will NOT deliver any Resultset that can be placed into the Pandas Dataframe (pd.read_sql).

If you just want to create the table, you don't need pandas:

```
session.execute(sqlStr);
```

If you want to read from the table "TEST123":

```
sqlStr = "SELECT col1 FROM Test123;";
result = pd.read_sql(sqlStr, self.session);
```

or alternatively:

```
result = pd.read_sql_table("Test123", self.session);
```

Comment: You are right. Now it worked! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To addon hhoeck answer, it is a good practice to use Context Manager. Otherwise you are risking having unclosed sessions.

```
import teradata
import pandas as pd

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="Hello", version="1.0",
                           logConsole=False)

with udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="tdprod",
                      username="xxx", password="xxx") as session:

    sqlStr = "CREATE SET TABLE \"TEST123\" \
             (col1 INTEGER) PRIMARY INDEX (col1);"
    # Create Table
    session.execute(sqlStr)

    # Read table to result

    result = pd.read_sql(sqlStr,session)
```

Comment: Prayson, is it possible to go further in your explanation? In which line the session is closed?

Comment: Sessions are automatically closed when the code exists the with ...: syntax. For a lengthy explanation see   https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/